# Find content inside JSON object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hash, filter

I have a JSON object like this:

```
[{
  "content.app" => {
    "type" => "content", "depends_on" => [],
    "primary" => {
      "id" => 1,
      "attributes" => {
        "data" => "my data"
      },
      "meta" => { "schema_version" => "1" }
    }
  }
 }, {
  "content.mongodb" => {
    "type" => "content", "depends_on" => [],
    "primary" => {
      "id" => 2,
      "attributes" => {
        "data" => "my data from app"
      }, "meta" => { "schema_version" => "1" }
    }
  }
 }, {
  "stuff.other" => {
    "type" => "content", "depends_on" => [],
    "primary" => {
      "id" => 2, "attributes" => {
        "data" => "my data from mongodb"
      }, "meta" => { "schema_version" => "1" }
    }
  }
}]
```

I'm looking for a result like:

```
"content.app" => "my data from app",
"content.mongodb" => "my data from mongodb"
```

How I can get the `attributes` from all the keys like `content.*`?

Comment: The first step would be to transform this structure into something closer to what you're looking for using `map`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, we expect to see an example of your effort. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? What code did you write toward solving this? Please read "[ask]" and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. SO isn't a "write code for me" site, it's a "help me fix the code I wrote" site, so showing what you have done is important.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to walk the data using `inject` and Ruby 2.3's `Hash#dig`:

```
data = ... # that array of hashes
data.inject({}){|h,v|
  v.inject(h){|h,(k,v)| h[k] = v.dig("primary", "attributes", "data"); h }
h}
# => {"content.app"=>"my data", "content.mongodb"=>"my data from app", "stuff.other"=>"my data from mongodb"}
```

Comment: Sometimes `each_with_object({ })` is a lot more clear and you don't have to remember to chain your hash through. Nice to see `Hash#dig` being used!

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation would be to pass each hash into a class that has the responsibility of extracting them. Something like:

```
class AttributesExtractor
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash
    @primary_key = hash.keys.first.to_s
  end

  def extract
    return unless primary_key_pattern?

    attr_data = hash[primary_key].dig('primary', 'attributes', 'data')

    if attr_data
      {hash.keys.first => attr_data}
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :hash, :primary_key

  def primary_key_pattern?
    primary_key.split('.').first.to_s == 'content'
  end
end

the_array_of_hash.map { |hash| AttributesExtractor.new(hash).extract }.compact
=> [{"content.app"=>"my data"}, {"content.mongodb"=>"my data from app"}]
```